# Should I be using scripting in this circumstance?

Tags: c++, scripting

I am writing a game. it is in c++ an direct x and I think I am making my own engine as I am programming from winproc up.

I have made large amounts of progress such as sound, collision detection, AI specific to my game settings, dynamic graphics creation from tile sheets.

after doing some research on event programming I have been told to "script it". I have researched this and as far as i see scripting is used so non programmers can add to the project.

I an a prety good programmer and I have no intention of having anyone else work on the game except on outside things such as graphics or map design. I already had a function where I can read in maps from csv files. these contain not just the tile layout but the npc data, entrances/exits. other files of the same nature control monster and item data so I can update the contents without a recompile.

So I am asking for the view of experienced programmers and maybe real world examples that relate to my circumstances as to why I should or should not use scripting in my game?

Comment: well, i think the answer is simply "dont script it".
if you are doing all the labor, and there is no one else touching the project, why should you script it?

BUT!...
allways think ahead, at some point if the game is succesfull,
it may get out of hand to do everything by yourself.
so maybe scripting it is not such a bad idea.

Comment: It sounds like you are making a game, not a game engine.  A game engine can be quickly reconfigured to run a different game and all but requires scripting.  Starting from wndproc has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @IronMensan yes I am making a game but I am not using anyone else's code as much as I can. I think what I am doing qualifies as making my own engine but im not sure. In all honesty I just want to make a game but it gets so complex so quickly I have no idea what you would call what I have made. I am building everything as one program so the "engine" is tailored to the game as in the animation function only animate thing I need for my specific game and cannot be adapted easily. Just wanted to know if I could continue to code the script stuff directly into the engine code or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think scripting is entirely necessary in your case.  The bonus behind adding scripting support an engine have been listed up and down this page.

- It gives you a simple langue to work with
- It is more accessible to someone without training
- It can be compiled on the fly, hot
  swapped at runtime

For lots of high end games with large teams these items are very important.  But it really comes down to the goals for your engine.  If you are not considering sharing your engine and plan to work on the game just yourself then scripting does loose some of its benefits.  Adding a scripting language also has some down sides.

- Add complexity and creation time to your engine
- Increase debug time, even if the scripting language has a wonderful debugger, switching between 2 languages is never smooth.

As long as you still have a data driven design (keeping stats and types in separate files which can be swapped out during runtime) you retain the ability to hot-swap out data for rapid iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The NPC and monster data need to be able to contain some simple logic like "if the player has this item", "if the player has been to somewhere", "if the player is comming from the right" etc. And for this you'll need ability to define some composed actions and conditionals. That is called scripting and is best done by incorporating some existing script language interpreter like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), [Python](http://www.python.org), some variant of JavaScript, whatever.

Comment: I have that logic already. When a monster is created the monster file is read and those condition are set in the AI part of the monster class. What im struggling with is how is doing it in script any different from writing it into c++

Comment: @Skeith: Than you have a simple form of scripting already. Now the easier it is to combine the individual bits (like 'does player have item with property x', 'does player have item with property x and has he been to y' etc.), the more you will be able to try out without recompiling the core and that will make you more efficient and it will allow somebody else to create interesting monsters and NPC without having to know the core. Now you can pick some small interpreter to do the combining (boolean operators, conditionals) or write your own, but you'll eventually end up with a language.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to use a scripting system in a game, not just as you pointed out, to allow non-programmers to add game content.  The first game I worked on professionally used a scripting system and the only people who were writing scripts were the programmers who created the scripting system.  There were two reasons they used it:

1. build times

   New data files/script files can be tested quickly.  This particular engine didn't support it, but some allow for script files to be reloaded while the game is running.  The more times you can iterate through the build-deploy-test cycle, the more you will be able to tweek your game and end up with a much better game.
2. power of expression

   A custimized scripting system can allow you to easily express/code concepts that are cumbersome in traditional programming.  For example, the game engine I am working with now allows me to easily control concurrent animations in script.

Answer (score 0):

definitivly add scripting. Its a pita to recompile the whole game, just because your player does 0.8 damage instead of 1.0. Also, If you want to have a door open under certain circumstances, you need it definitfly. I would do most of the game in a scripting language, Its just more flexible.

Big names are using scripting languages. For example Eve Online is written in stackless python. Other examples can be found here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames

Comment: I like using c++, im not sure why but I just don't enjoy programming in other languages,(have tried vb and java) so doing the bare minimum in c++ and the rest in lua doesn't sound fun to me. and it still needs to be coded so what's the difference using a script to built in c++ ?

Comment: If you're planning to do a mass amount of AI-s, maps, scenarios, then it might be faster to script them.

Comment: @shambu49: It's going to be slow at run-time, too.

Comment: @Skeith: It's definitely not about bare minimum in C++. You still want to do much of the work in C++. What you just want is flexibility in tying the things together from map data.

Comment: @Shambu49 the game loads in the info for the area the player is in such as monsters you can encounter and their data, the map such as a castle layout and npc. only the relevant information is stored and replaced when the player moves to a new area such as the space between the castle and town.

Comment: I was referring to the speed of development, sorry for confusing :)